# iOS pausing camera iris CATransition halfway

Tags: iphone, ios, caanimation, catransition

I'm trying to control the shutter animation of a custom imagepicker using

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
animation.type = @"cameraIris";
```

and would like to pause the shutter in the middle and resume it later.

I've tried two approaches that don't seem to work for me:

1. Pausing it after x seconds, but this pauses the layer at random places
2. Using 2 transitions with `cameraIrisHollowClose` and `cameraIrisHollowOpen` along with `animationDidFinish`, I notice that the first `CATransition` goes away and there's a small delay before the second one shows up.

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to do this so that the animation seems smooth.